# Rspec POST: create tests failing with undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have a Rails (4.1.8) application with Rspec (3.1.0) and FactoryGirl (4.5.0) for testing. My controller tests for the post create action fail with the following error:

```
Failure/Error: post :create, { member_id: @member, fitness_goal: @fitness_goal_attributes }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass
```

The fitness goal factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

factory :fitness_goal do
association :goal_list
association :timeframe
start_date Date.current
end_date Date.current + 30
targets { [create(:target, outcome: "Lose Fat"), create(:target, outcome: "Reduce caloric intake by x%")] }
activities { [create(:activity, description: "Walk x steps a day"), create(:activity, description: "Climb x floors a day"), create(:activity, description: "Run x mile a day")] }   
association :member
association :trainer
notes 'This is a sample note.'
end
end
```

The relevant FactoryGirl instance variable:

```
@fitness_goal_attributes = FactoryGirl.build(:fitness_goal).attributes
```

I'm using the Array reject method in my Fitness Goals Controller's create action:

```
def create
  unless params[:fitness_goal].blank? && params[:activity_ids].blank? && params[:target_ids].blank?
  params[:fitness_goal][:activity_ids] = params[:fitness_goal][:activity_ids].reject{ |activity_ids| activity_ids.empty? }   
  params[:fitness_goal][:target_ids] = params[:fitness_goal][:target_ids].reject{ |target_ids| target_ids.empty? }      
  @fitness_goal = @member.fitness_goals.build(fitness_goal_params)

  if @fitness_goal.save 
    flash[:success] = "Fitness goal was successfully created."
    redirect_to member_fitness_goals_path(@member)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 end
end
```

The fitness goal params:

```
def fitness_goal_params
  params.require(:fitness_goal).permit(:goal_list_id, :timeframe_id, :start_date, :end_date, { target_ids: [] }, { activity_ids: [] }, :notes, :member_id, :trainer_id)
 end
```

**** EDIT ******
Results from binding.pry / Better Errors:

```
params[:fitness_goal][:activity_ids]
=> ["12", "10", "11"]

params[:fitness_goal][:target_ids]
=> ["1", "2"]

 params[:fitness_goal]
 => {"goal_list_id"=>"1", "timeframe_id"=>"2", "start_date"=>"2015-12-16", "end_date"=>"2016-01-15", "target_ids"=>["1", "2"], "activity_ids"=>["12", "10", "11"], "trainer_id"=>"", "notes"=>"testing"}
```

***** EDIT *****

The application works as expected in development and production environments but Rspec throws the error for all tests of the POST create method. I can't figure out why the unless statement is not acting as a "nil guard" when I call the reject method on the arrays. What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve the error?

Comment: It's coming from line 3 or 4 in FitnessGoalsController.create

Comment: @Andrew Williamson - As I mentioned in my question, I'm aware of where the error is coming from in the controller.  I'm just stuck on how to resolve it.

Comment: Well a good place to start would be printing the params variable, and making sure that params[:fitness_goal][:activity_ids] and params[:fitness_goal][:target_ids] are both defined

Comment: Using Pry / Better Errors, I can confirm that both params variables are defined.

Comment: It really looks like they're not.  Can you `pry` your create method, run the test, and then examine `fitness_goal_params` and maybe edit your question to include the value?

Comment: I added results from binding.pry / Better Errors.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 bugs on your code which could explain that:

1. you use `&&` operator when your probably mean to use `||`
2. You check for `params[:activity_ids]` but try to use `params[:fitness_goal][:activity_ids]`

so you could change:

```
unless params[:fitness_goal].blank? && params[:activity_ids].blank? && params[:target_ids].blank?
```

by:

```
unless params[:fitness_goal].blank? || params[:fitness_goal][:activity_ids].blank? || params[:fitness_goal][:target_ids].blank?
```

Comment: I changed the unless statement but still getting the error:  NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yes there is another error on the unless statement, I will edit my response

Comment: you could also simplify your code by using reject! method

Comment: The revised unless statement triggers a new error:   ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template fitness_goals/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
         * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x00000005794758>"

Comment: your in the case when unless contition is true. following your code, in this case the create method just does nothing; no render nor redirect is called. If you indent your code correctly, that will show your thing more clearly.

Comment: Any more ideas on how to solve the problem that's causing the test to fail when the reject method is called?  BTW, thanks for the suggestion to use reject! instead of reject.

Comment: you could call `render 'new'` when the unless condition is true.